# Check if Internal IP with Django

Tags: django, ip

I am trying to create a function that will return `True` or `False` depending on if the ip address of the user is an internal or external IP address. We would like internal users to be able to see more things and have more access. We're looking to do this as 'inexpensively' as possible. I know how to query the general IP and use conditional logic against a tuple. What I'm wondering is can Django do most of this for me?

Example:

```
if request.is_internal():
    #Do Special Secret Internal Stuff Things!
```

I've read a bit about Django's [INTERNAL_IPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#internal-ips) but it seems to only be used for debugging, and will not allow me to call it. Am I wrong on that?

Comment: You can create a custom auth backend, and do custom processing on login if `settings.INTERNAL_IPS in request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create a view decorator which checks the remote address, then raises a 403 when the remote address is not in `settings.INTERNAL_IPS`, like so:

```
import functools

from django.conf import settings
from django import http
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


def internal_or_403(view_func):
    """
    A view decorator which returns the provided view function,
    modified to return a 403 when the remote address is not in
    the list of internal IPs defined in settings.
    """
    @functools.wraps(view_func)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] not in settings.INTERNAL_IPS:
            return http.HttpResponseForbidden('<h1>Forbidden</h1>')
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class Internal(object):
    """
    A mix-in for class based views, which disallows requests from
    non-internal IPs.
    """
    @method_decorator(internal_or_403)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Internal, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```